# Spotify application - maintaing state between pages

Tags: javascript, css, html, spotify

Firend i am developing spotify application & according to their developers site i come to understand that i can use only HTML/HTML5 , javascript, css for development
Now i am having some question regarding development:
I am having multiple pages & for each page i am having certain input parameters & i want to track these parameter throughtout application
such as user name taken as input from user.
How can i do that ,
is there any kind of session management tool or something like that?
How can i process mydata from different page to show desired result.

Comment: you could save certain information as a cookie in your browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [API Guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/), you are able to take advantage of the `HTML localStorage API`:

> Your application will be able to use the local storage HTML5 API which as a limited amount of space available to your application (5 MB). Please be aware that any state you save here will be local, and hence you won’t be able to restore from it if the user logs into Spotify on another computer and browses to your application.
>   To restore state regardless of which computer a user is currently using, please use your own backend.

Comprehensive documentation on how you can interact with `localStorage` can be found on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).

It boils down to using `window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and `window.localStorage.getItem(key)` to set and retrieve data.